# Scrolling down a page using a button on jquery

Tags: jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
        $(".movescroll").scrollTop(50);
    });
});
```

What I want to do is get the position of the scroll and keep moving it up and down 50px. what mine does only moves it to the location.

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to repeatedly go up and down, again and again?

Comment: So you want to repeatedly make the screen scroll up and down? Wouldn't that not only make it difficult for the viewer to interact with your site, but also make them nauseous?

Comment: On the click event of the "Move Down" button, make the scrollbar on the "area3" element scroll down 50px from its current position.

 On the click event of the "Move Up" button, make the scrollbar on the "area3" element scroll up 50px from its current position

these are the questions asked of me to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following variable to get the actual scroll 
`var actualScroll = $(window).scrollTop();` and simply replace your value (50) by `actualScroll + 50`